# Free tool to compress images to a given file size

Tags: file-compression, gif, png, jpg

Is there a tool (preferably a webapp) to which you upload an image (let's say 100Kb) and specify the desired reduced file size (let's say 50Kb), then download the result which should be roughly the desired size?

It should just support standard images, but including animated GIF.

Just like this screenshot, only for images:

[image: Reduce video file size]

Comment: If I understood you right you are not asking for looseles compression?

Comment: No need to lossless. I want a reduced quality image but just by specifying the desired reduced file size.

Comment: OK, because looseles compression in general wouldn´t work this way. But which output format(s) the compressed images should be? Only the same as input ones?

Comment: Yes, same format as input.

Comment: To be honest I don´t know any tool or webapp, where you can select the exact output size, but there are many webapps where you can select the compression quality and ratio for sze reduction.

Answer (score 2):

Available on most systems, the ImageMagick package's `convert` command has far more image conversion options than anyone would ever need (literally hundreds).

```
$ convert  -resize 50%   input.jpeg   output.png
$ convert  -define jpeg:extent=9mb   input.png   output.jpeg
```

(Just be aware of its potentially dangerous syntax, where the output file is a positional argument.)

Comment: ImageMagick is also available for Windows, MacOS, Android or iOS.

Answer (score 0):

So the clothest would be [this webapp](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/compress-image-size.php), but the output format is only JPG. However [this webapp](https://imagecompressor.11zon.com/en/compress-jpg/) could give you posibly a beter quality, but you can only select the compression ratio and no exact output size.